# Hand over NULL shared pointer to reference?

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr

Within (existing) code a shared pointer implementation "xBinSp" is used which is mainly similar to std::shared_ptr. There are some methods defined as

```
setBinaryValue(xBinSp &bin);
```

where such shared pointer objects have to be handed over. Now there are situations where NULL (means xBinSp()) would have to be handed over.

Calling

```
setBinaryValue(xBinSp());
```

leads to an warning

warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'xBinSp' to 'xBinSp&'

So my question: how can I correctly hand over something "NULL"-like in such a case when the method expects a reference to such a shared pointer? Creating an own variable and using it seems to be some waste of resources to me...

Thanks!

Comment: I'd just pass `xBinSp`.

Comment: I see the mechanics are explained in the answers but why just don't call the function at all. It has other side effects other then modifying the parameter?

Comment: The function HAS to be called defined by logic of the application itself to reset an other binary value that may have been set earlier. So it is a legal state to hand over no binary data (aka NULL pointer aka empty shared pointer) to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create an overload for the function with zero parameters:

```
void setBinaryValue() {
    xBinSp bin;
    setBinaryValue(bin);
}
```

an call this one for empty values.

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you call the function with `xBinSp()` you are creating a *temporary* value which will be destroyed as soon as the function call is done, and as the function wants a reference, you give the function a reference to this temporary value.

The simplest solution is to declare the function taking a `const` reference:

```
setBinaryValue(const xBinSp & bin);
```

If you can't do that, then you have to create a non-temporary instance, and pass that to the function:

```
xBinSp null;
setBinaryValue(null);
```

In both cases though, you have to take care that the function does not save this reference for future access.

Answer (score 0):

You pass objects by reference when you want to change their values:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void swap(T1 & t1, T2 & t2)
{
    T1 tmp = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = tmp;
}
```

So if you call `swap(a,b)`, after the function call `a` will have the value of `b` and vice versa. This does not work with temporaries.

Since C++11 there is a way around this - rvalue references:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void swap(T1 && t1, T2 && t2)
{
    T1 tmp = t1;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = std::move(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is warning you that it is using a non-standard extension of C++, that is, it is binding a temporary value (`xBinSp()`) to a reference to non-const (`xBinSp&`) which is not normally not allowed.

Temporaries can only bind to reference to const and their lifetime gets extended to that of the reference their are bound to.

The name of the function `setBinaryValue` implies (though I could be wrong) that it sets some value to its argument. Now, it think it wouldn't make much sense to pass it a temporary because it would be destroyed when the function returns and you couldn't make use the value. The problem remains even if you change the signature to take a `const xBinSp&`.

Passing it a named lvalue would be your best bet, IMO.